# Showing that an integral operator is bounded on a hilbert space.

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Im trying to understand how it was hsown that T is a bounded operator on H. Going through the proof I don't understand what justifies the convergence of the last integral in this proof? What is it referring to when it talks about numerators and denominators? What is r?

Isn't it sufficient to say that |x-y| is bounded because they're inside the unit ball?

[part 1 of proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icKq0.png)

[part 2 of proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5tIu.png)

Answer (score 1):

If we integrate over the ball in $\mathbb R^d$ you can write (essentially as an extension of polar or spherical coordinates to the n-dimensional case)
\begin{align*}
M\int_{B(0,1)} |f(y)|^2|x-y|^{-d+\alpha}dy &= M\int_{\partial B(0,1)}\int_0^1 |f(r)|^2r^{-d+\alpha}r^{d-1}drdS\\
&= M\int_{\partial B(0,1)}\int_0^1 |f(r)|^2r^{\alpha}drdS,
\end{align*}
where the $r^{d-1}$ term comes from your change of variables. This integral must be convergent since $f$ is bounded.

I believe saying $|x-y|$ is bounded is not sufficient because for a fixed $x \in B(0,1)$ and $d>\alpha$ we have that $|x-y|^{-d+\alpha}$ is large when $y$ is close to $x$

Comment: That change of variables seems really complicated. could you explain further how this change of variables is done or link me to a source on how to do this? I still don't see how $r^{-d+\alpha}r^{d-1}$ comes out.

Comment: [Here's the wiki page on it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Direct_integration_in_spherical_coordinates) The idea is that you integrate over the radius, and then integrate over the surface of the ball. So, on the unit ball in 2d you go to polar by
$$\int_{B(0,1)}dy  = \int_{\partial B(0,1)}\int_0^1rdrdS,$$
and in 3d
$$\int_{B(0,1)}dy = \int_{\partial B(0,1)}\int_0^1r^2 drdS.$$
So for the n-dimensional case you would do
$$\int_{B(0,1)}dy  = \int_{\partial B(0,1)}\int_0^1r^{n-1}drdS.$$